# Increment ngClass value

Tags: angular, typescript

How to increment a class numeric value using `ngClass`?

e.g. - `<some-element [ngClass]="'class-*'">...</some-element>` , where `*` should auto-increment until met conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i:number = 0;
```

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'class-'+ i">...</some-element>
<button (click)="i = i+1">increment</button>
```

(I'm not sure if `i++` work in a template)

Comment: Is it possible to add a secondary class?

Comment: What is a secondary class? When do you want to add it? What name should it have?

Comment: `"'class' + i class-secondary"` , something like this

Comment: Why do you think you need `ngClass` for that? What about `class="class-secondary"`?

Comment: Oh.. excuse me, still digesting the coffee :D

Comment: You can also do `[ngClass]="'class-'+ i + ' class-secondary'"` but I'd add static classes using `class="foo bar"` and only dynamic classes with Angular bindings